# Can I share an excel file that has a link to a text file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharing

I have an Excel file that pulls data from a text file using the "Get Data From Text" option. When I try to share the document using the Review/Share Document option, the option to refresh the data from the linked text file is disabled.

Is there any way to have a linked text file that can be shared with other users in Excel?

This is on an internal network and we do not use Sharepoint.

Comment: "Is there any way to have a linked text file that can be shared with other users in Excel?"  - You can share the excel document, the values just can't be changed or updated, unless the linked file is in the exact same location.

Comment: The data in the linked text file does not need to be changed, it is just read only. But the user can copy and paste it into other sheets. But the problem is when I choose "sharing" the "refresh" button is disabled. Any workaround?

Comment: "But the problem is when I choose "sharing" the "refresh" button is disabled." - Provide them the text file and have them place it in the exact same location.  In other words, without the source file, they won't be able to refresh the data for obvious reasons.

Comment: The source file is in a network share they all can access. The problem is that the excel file I'm using has other sheets that need to be edited using the source file's data.

Comment: If they open their own copy of the workbook, the option to refresh the data, will be enabled.  Your likely running into a feature limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Excel does not allow you to share a file that is linked to a text file.